Using FromBody with custom model binding in .NET Core 8
X is an entity that can execute some actions on through calling API.
Each action has its own input model, but one generic controller endpoint like this:
[HttpPost("{id}/execute-action")]
public async Task<IActionResult> 
    ExecuteAction([FromRoute] Guid id,
                  [FromBody]
                  [ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(ActionInputModelBinder))] 
                  ExecuteActionInputModel model)
{
    return await _service.ExecuteActionAsync(id, model);
}

All actions input models must use or inherit from ExecuteActionInputModel:
public class ExecuteActionInputModel
{
    [Required]
    public required MyActionEnum ActionName { get; set; }
}

To be able to bind models at runtime, I am using custom model binder with custom provider as per this link from Microsoft Docs.
This is the custom binder:
public class ActionInputModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    private readonly IDictionary<Type, (ModelMetadata, IModelBinder)> _propertyBinders;

    internal ActionInputModelBinder(IDictionary<Type, (ModelMetadata, IModelBinder)> propertyBinders)
    {
        _propertyBinders = propertyBinders;
    }

    public async Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext modelBindingContext)
    {
        var actionNameValue = modelBindingContext.ValueProvider
                                                 .GetValue(nameof(ExecuteActionInputModel.ActionName)).FirstValue;

        if (actionNameValue == null)
        {
            modelBindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Failed();
            return;
        }

        var actionName = Enum.Parse<RequestActionEnum>(actionNameValue);
    }
}

The problem is that ValueProvider always returning nulls when using [FromBody], but the code executes as expected when using [FromForm].

You could try to parse from the request bodystream manually:
    public class ActionInputModelBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        public async Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext modelBindingContext)
        {
            if (modelBindingContext == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(modelBindingContext));
            }

            var request = modelBindingContext.HttpContext.Request;

            if (!request.Body.CanSeek)
            {
                request.EnableBuffering();
            }

            request.Body.Position = 0;
            using var reader = new StreamReader(request.Body);
            var body = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(body))
            {
                modelBindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Failed();
                return;
            }
            try
            {
                var model = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ExecuteActionInputModel>(body, new JsonSerializerOptions
                {
                    PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true,                
                }) ;
                var actionName = model.ActionName;

                modelBindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(model);
            }
            catch (JsonException)
            {
                modelBindingContext.ModelState.TryAddModelError(modelBindingContext.ModelName, "Invalid JSON.");
                modelBindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Failed();
            }

            request.Body.Position = 0;
        }
    }

